# Does aws s3 sync count as requests?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I recently used `aws s3 sync` to mirror a small server (about 4.5M files, 12TB). If I were to run `aws s3 sync` again, would I get charged for another ~4.5M requests or would only the files that are updated/new be counted as requests?

In general, how are requests counted when using `aws s3 sync`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`sync` will list all necessary objects, taking as many paginated list requests as necessary. Each list returns 1000 objects. It then does any required gets/puts, but only for objects that have been updated as far as it can tell based on the response elements from the list calls. So in your case there will be ~4,500 list calls + one get/put for each object which has changed.

Comment: I can't think of any quick way to verify your answer, but the fact that _you work for Amazon_ suffices for me! Thanks :)

Comment: If you would like to independently verify this, you can review the source code: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/tree/develop/awscli/customizations/s3

Comment: As per the source code it is using ls, which will only display objects within a folder. If 4.5M files are distributed with only 100 objects under each folder I am assuming it will be 45,000 calls. Please verify @JordonPhillips Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'folder' for S3. There are only string keys and blob values. The layout of your keys and common prefixes do not impact sync beyond setting a source / destination prefix.

Comment: I see the following line in the source.. aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive --human-readable --summarize I think that answers my doubt. Thanks Jordon!